# How do I connect MySQL using Perl/CGI in Mac OS Sierra?

Tags: mysql, macos, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print "content-type:text/html\n\n";
print "<html><body>";
use CGI;
use DBI;
use CGI qw(:standard);
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
$db="New";
$user="root";
$password="isRovss*%1u";
$host="localhost";
$dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password) || 
die "couldnt open database:$DBI :: errstr";

$sth=$dbh->prepare("select * from stud");
$rv=$sth->execute();
print "<table>";
print "<tr><th>id</th></tr><tr><th>name</th></tr><tr><th>age</th> 
</tr>";
while (@row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    $id=$row[0];
    $name=$row[1];
    $age=$row[2];;
}
print "<tr><td>$id</td></tr><tr><td>$name</td></tr><tr><td>$age</td> 
</tr>";
print "</table>";
$rc=$sth->finish();
print "Database closed";
print "</body></html>";
```

I am trying to connect the mysql database using Perl. I am using a Mac OS and it says "Couldn't connect database".

The code im using is given above. Please help me out.

Comment: Is there a database running on that machine? Can you connect to it via the command line with the `mysql` command and the same credentials?

Comment: Your code is very old-fashioned. If you've got this from a book, please use a more modern book. It's teaching you outdated things. You should start by adding `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of your code, then declare your variables with `my`.

Comment: Thank you for the input, @simbabque. I do not have any coding experience, so I followed this from the Internet. I will try using strict and warning commands.

Comment: There are a lot of good resources for learning modern Perl linked in [the Perl tag wiki here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/perl/info). Take a look at those and forget about the tutorial you're doing now. You're making your life hard right now. :)

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.640/DBI.pm#connect)

> ```
> $dbh = DBI->connect($data_source, $username, $password, \%attr)
>         or die $DBI::errstr;
> ```

Compare to your code:

> ```
> $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password) 
>         || die "couldnt open database:$DBI :: errstr";
> ```

You've put `$DBI::errstr` *inside* a string literal, and added spaces.

This means your error message reporting code is going to try to try report `$DBI` (followed by `:: errstr`) instead of the variable containing the error.

Fix that and you can find out what is actually wrong:

```
$dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db:$host",$user,$password) 
        || die "couldnt open database:" . $DBI::errstr;
```

Answer (score 2):

Using CGI is an unnecessary distraction here. I recommend that you try writing a non-CGI program that connects to the database first and, when you get that working, you can copy the same connection code into your CGI program.

In fact, even before that, you should ensure that you can use your connection details to connect to the MySQL server using the standard MySQL tools.

What happens if you open a command line window and run the following?:

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p -D New
```

Almost certainly, this is a problem with connecting to the database and has nothing to do with Perl or CGI.